# Efficiently SELECT either a real record or a virtual/default "record" in .NET/T-SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a structure to work with data from a loaded .NET Dataset from a single query.  I have a table designed to override my application driven default values. To demonstrate build the settings override table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
    PK int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VALINT int NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION1 varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

My code will generate SQL with the built-in defaults UNIONed with the custom override data from the table into a query and return the single dataset:

```
SELECT C.VALINT, C.DESCRIPTION1
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(PK)AS PK, VALINT
        FROM (
            SELECT PK, VALINT
            FROM TABLE1
            UNION
            SELECT 0, 1
            UNION
            SELECT 0, 2
        ) A
        GROUP BY VALINT
    )B, (
        SELECT PK, VALINT, DESCRIPTION1
        FROM TABLE1
        UNION
        SELECT 0, 1, 'Default1Val'
        UNION
        SELECT 0, 2, 'Default2Val'
    ) C
    WHERE B.PK = C.PK AND B.VALINT = C.VALINT
```

Run this query against the empty table and you will see just the two default settings defined in the query. Then a new custom override can be added:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(VALINT,DESCRIPTION1)VALUES(1,'CustomOverride1')
```

Now re-run the above query and you will see the one custom value from the table and the one remaining non-overridden default value. This query does exactly what I need, however when done this way, the data from the table is being UNIONed with default setting data two different times. Is there a more elegant query possible with a single set of UNIONs or am I stuck with two full sets of UNIONs as demonstrated above?

Comment: I think if you use a combination of `ISNULL` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` correctly, you should be able to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a Common Table Expression ([CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) is very useful.

I've also corrected your join - comma separated joins (old style joins) are not recommended, instead use the explicit join type.

```
declare @TABLE1 table (
    PK int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VALINT int NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION1 varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PK, VALINT, DESCRIPTION1
    FROM @TABLE1
    UNION
    SELECT 0, 1, 'Default1Val'
    UNION
    SELECT 0, 2, 'Default2Val'
)
SELECT C.VALINT, C.DESCRIPTION1
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(PK)AS PK, VALINT
    FROM cte A
    GROUP BY VALINT
) B
inner join cte C on B.PK = C.PK AND B.VALINT = C.VALINT;
```

Returns:

```
VALINT  DESCRIPTION1
1       Default1Val
2       Default2Val
```

Adding a custom override gives:

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE1 (VALINT,DESCRIPTION1) VALUES(1,'CustomOverride1');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PK, VALINT, DESCRIPTION1
    FROM @TABLE1
    UNION
    SELECT 0, 1, 'Default1Val'
    UNION
    SELECT 0, 2, 'Default2Val'
)
SELECT C.VALINT, C.DESCRIPTION1
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(PK)AS PK, VALINT
    FROM cte A
    GROUP BY VALINT
) B
inner join cte C on B.PK = C.PK AND B.VALINT = C.VALINT;
```

Returns:

```
VALINT  DESCRIPTION1
2       Default2Val
1       CustomOverride1
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to choose what you need to use for solve your task. 
Join is used to combine columns from different tables, the union is used to combine rows

When you union two table there are a couple of requirements for them

1. The number of columns must be the same for both select statements
2. The columns, in order, must be of the same data type